# Formatting text in Cricket 'overs' format?

Tags: vb6

I am making a VB6 Project to show Statistics of a cricket match. In 'overs' textbox, I want to show the current over and balls in the format 'over.ball' ( ex:- 6.2 , 12.5 ) I have currently set up an 'up' button which add '0.1' to the text box when clicked. When i click the 'up' button, If the current value of the textbox is '0.5' , It must become '1' [or '1.0'] instead of '0.6' .

Here's the code i added for the 'up' command.

```
Private Sub up_Click()
overs.Text = overs.Text + 0.1
End Sub
```

[Preview of the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lIlHJ.png)
[Code for the 'up' command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAuTm.png)

So, what's the format i must use in the textbox to show the overs as said above?

*Note : Sorry! I am a new to VB6. So please tell me if you want some more information about the question. Hope an answer from you. Thank you!*

Comment: The Round function (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/aa242034(v%3dvs.60)) will round 0.5 or 0.6 up to 1.0.  But just throwing a Round call in there probably isn't what you need since 0.4 will be rounded down to 0.0.  So this is really a question about the specifics of Cricket scoring - I doubt you'll find a lot of expertise in Cricket here at SO, so you'll need to be very specific in your requirements in order to receive proper assistance here.

Comment: Everyone knows cricket. There are 6 balls an over, and there is 20, 50, or unlimited overs per innings. In unlimited overs, matches are two innings per team and the match is limited to 30 hours over 5 days. To win you must score more runs AND dismiss the other teams innings twice. `Let` coercion allows us to treat your number as a string `If Right(x,2) = ".5" then x = x + 1 - 0.5`.

Comment: Historically (players are better now) 50% of games have no result making wins hard to get.

Comment: Important to note that the code snippet I gave won't work on a German computer, they use `,` as the decimal point. But they don't play cricket in Germany. When you do stuff yourself you lose Windows automatically looking after international issues.

Comment: @Noodles - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germany_national_cricket_team.   Oops.  :)

Comment: I think it might be better to model the delivery behaviour in a class.  Internally that class could maintain an integer for 'over' and another for 'ball'.  Then you can just have methods to AddDelivery which can contain the logic to increment 'ball' and if necessary 'over'.  Add a ToString style method to format the output for display by concatenating the two integers either side of '.'.  I'd knock something up but I've not got access to a VB6 compiler at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done this in Excel as I don't have VB6 but you might be able to take something useful from it.
I created a new class module called Innings:

```
Private m_Over As Integer
Private m_Ball As Integer
Public Sub BowlDelivery()
    If m_Ball = 5 Then
        m_Ball = 0
        m_Over = m_Over + 1
    Else
        m_Ball = m_Ball + 1
    End If
End Sub
Public Function ToString() As String
    ToString = Format(m_Over, "##0") + "." + Format(m_Ball, "0")
End Function
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    m_Over = 0
    m_Ball = 0
End Sub
```

This class encapsulates the behaviour of bowling a delivery and how that affects the over number and ball within that over.  The method ToString then formats these values for the normal way you'd display on a score display.

You can then use this class like this:

```
Public Sub TestInnings()
    Dim EnglandFirstInnings As New Innings
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To 100
        Debug.Print EnglandFirstInnings.ToString()
        EnglandFirstInnings.BowlDelivery
    Next
End Sub
```

If you've not used your own classes in VB6 it might be worthwhile doing some background reading on that topic as they are a great way to hide away complexity.